# Using JQuery to change text of a div from a list of text files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to create a simple text translator, I know how to change texts of a div using JQuery at the moment. However I want to change it according to a text file.

This is the code which I can the text values with.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="textChange">Text before it's changed</div>
        <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="click to change"/>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // A $( document ).ready() block.
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            $( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {
              $("#textChange").html("Updated text, after button click.");
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

What I am looking to do now is to have say 2 buttons, 1 button for English and another for say French. When the website loads I want it to display in English and when the button is clicked for it to change the text to French.

I will have both texts as text files so I would like to load them each time one button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

**Html**
The two required buttons and the area for the text change

```
<div id="textChange">Text before it's changed</div>
<button type="button" data-lang="french">French</button>
<button type="button" data-lang="english">English</button>
```

**Js**

2 variables are created for each file path. A function is created to to pass the file into the [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method which will retrieve the file ( get is more general and the callback handles the success response of AJAX call where you are free to define any behaviour you want).

This is based on a conditional defined by the button's `data-lang` attribute assignment in the html.

```
$(function () {

    var englishFilePath = "../Content/english.txt",
        frenchFilePath = "../Content/french.txt";

        function chgLang(lang){
            $.get(lang, function(data) {
                //process text file line by line
                $('#textChange').html(data.replace('n','<br />'));
            });
        };

        $("button[data-lang]").click(function () {

            $(this).data("lang") === "french" ? chgLang(frenchFilePath) : chgLang(englishFilePath);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi I've tried adding this but upon pressing the button there is no change.

Comment: @unclemeat This is an answer, it has been tested, and it does work. So either the OP needs to be more clear on the issues he is facing , or provide more detail to what he would like to achieve

Comment: @NeoSeekr If you are accessing the file outside of your server , you might want to check that the text file on that server has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` equally to the path of that file.

Comment: @gerdi Sorry buddy, must have clicked the wrong auto-comment - I just meant to suggest that you add some more information to go with your post.

Comment: @unclemeat .. i updated my answer .. also how do you add an auto-comment?

Comment: @gerdi When you have enough reputation, you can 'review' posts, there is a set list of comments that you can flag an item with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {
    $("#textChange").load("file.txt");
    });
});
```

This works. However this has no line breaks where there should be.

I guess I could have text files with `<br>` in them for now. Would be better if there was a way to go through the text file line by line.